# jquery selector to filter out th elements

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
```

This selects all rows.  However, not all tables have thead and tbody explicitly defined, so I need to filter *out* any rows that have .children('th')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm assuming you wanted to filter *out* the rows that have `<th>` elements. If you wanted to end up with *only* those rows, then just get rid of the `:not()` part.

---

This will give you `<tr>` elements in the table that do not have a descendant `<th>`.

```
var rows = $table.find('tr:not(:has(th))').get();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Note that this will also give consideration to nested tables. If there will be nested tables with `<th>` tags, try this:

```
var rows = $table.find('tr:not(:has( > th))').get();
```

...which should limit the consideration of the `<th>` tags to immediate children.

Answer (score -1):

Why not change that to:

```
var rows = $table.find('tr > th').get();
```

EDIT:

```
var rows = $table.find("tr:has(th)").get();
```

Comment: spinon - This would actually select the `<th>` elements. I think OP wants to select the `<tr>` elements.