# select rows in a table except the table header rows

Tags: jquery, html

How to select rows in a html table except the table header rows using jquery?

```
 <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Foo
                </th>
                <td>
                    Lorem
                </td>
                <td>
                    Ipsum
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Bar
            </th>
            <td>
                Dolor
            </td>
            <td>
                Sit
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Baz
            </th>
            <td>
                Amet
            </td>
            <td>
                Consectetuer
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339172/jquery-selector-to-filter-out-th-elements

This question is in SO numerous times in different variations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('tr').not('thead tr').addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 24):

You should wrap the rows in a `<tbody>` element (some browsers will do this **anyway**!), then select the children of that tbody:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr');
```

Answer (score 5):

This selector selects all tr elements in #mytable except the first one (the header).

```
$('#mytable tr:not(:first)')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude `thead` using [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('#mytable tr').not('thead tr')
```