# Bad Request Check all data table Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm having a trouble why it keeps telling the console bad request after I check all the data, but if I manually check each item on table it works fine, but when I use check all - bad request I think the problem it has "on" data on my table. Is there any expert can know about this?Im begginner of django and javascript please suggest if anyone know about this thanks in advance

> Bad Request using check all

[image: Bad Request check all]

> Check manually

[image: Manual]

> table.html

```
<button type="submit" id="delete_btn" class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" >Mark 
 as Paid</button>
<table class="table" name="table" id="table">
            <thead>
              <tr >
                <th >No</th>
                <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th >Name</th>
                <th >Barangay</th>
                <th >Sex</th>
                <th >Sector</th>
                <th Amount</th>
                <th >Signature/Thumb Marks</th>
                <th >ID Presented/ Date & Issuance</th>
                <th>Date Received</th>
                <th >Remarks</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="report-content">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for user_information in benefeciaries %}
              <tr id="{{user_information.id}}">
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" value="{{user_information.id}}" 
                id="delete_product"></td>
                <td>{{user_information.covid_id}} </td>
                <td>{{user_information.lastname}}, {{user_information.firstname}} 
                {{user_information.middle}}</td>
                <td width="5%">{{user_information.barangay}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td ></td>
                <td>{{user_information.amount|floatformat:2|intcomma}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}  
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

> javascript

```
//js checkall
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
 }
 }

//js mark as paid button
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete_btn').click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure ?")){
      var id =[];
      var csrf=$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
      $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        id[i]=$(this).val()
      })

      if(id.length===0){
        alert("please select item ")
      }
      else{
        console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url:"/delete/",
            method:"POST",
            data: {
              id,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf
            },
            success:function(response){        
              Swal.fire({title:"Successfully saved!",text:"Mark As Paid",type:"success",confirmButtonClass:"btn btn-success",buttonsStyling:!1})
            }

          })
      }
    }
  })
});
```

> views.py ajax

```
def delete(request):
   if request.method=="POST":
       product_ids=request.POST.getlist('id[]')
       for id in product_ids:
          Person.objects.filter(pk=id).update(paid=1)
       return redirect('dashboard')
```

Comment: How can I not include "on" when submit data? please

Comment: could you provide the forms and view for that too?

Comment: @markus thanks for your response do you mean my views.py?

Comment: @markus I added my viewspy above ajax thanks could you help me? Im out of option

Comment: I think the problem is on my javascript is there any missing? Im confused

Comment: I think the problem lies within `$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){ id[i]=$(this).val() })`. If you select all checkboxes, which are checked, then you'll eventually also get the one on top too. Maybe change jQuery selector to something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350950/876847

Comment: @markus thanks for your response yes, that's also I think but until now I don't know how can I not include the upper checkbox. I already check that link before , please help

Comment: @markus how about changing the checkbox on the upper top into button or span? instead of checkbox?

Comment: That would work, or you apply something like `$(':checkbox:checked').not('thead tr')` then you would not fetch your checkbox in your table header ... that should pretty much do it.

Comment: @markus thanks for your respons, I tried like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJDNA.png)  instead of this [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HojxT.png) but the result is always the same please

Comment: `$('.report-content:checkbox:checked')`also does not work? this should select your content and then all checkboxes that are checked